# Using a static Handler class, referencing external TextView

Tags: android

I'm a novice at Java and Android programing, although I have done some extensive PHP coding, so I understand most concepts fairly quickly. What I don't know is "the way" to do things.

As a practice app, I want to code a Fast Fourier Transform app that shows me the recorded audio spectrum (I'm a physics major, so this seems like a worthwhile and fun little project.) (Yes, I know it's been done before).

So far I've set up the AudioRecord reader and I got it to read bytes, I figured out I need to create a Thread which posts to a Handler if I want to keep it running in the background without freezing the app, and I figured out how to pass data to the Handler. For now it's just displaying the bytes in a TextView in the MainActivity, so I can "see" something is happening.

Where I'm stuck is that apparently because my Handler isn't static, GC trashes something (I don't know what) after a few seconds of my app running flawlessly, and it crashes. After some reading, I seem to have figured out I need to extend Handler and implement some WeakReference, but, in all honesty, it's getting to the point where I don't know what I'm doing. If anyone could explain what exactly is going on here, or how I can reference my TextView from some external class, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance, EastWind

Here's the code:

```
private Handler uiCallback = new Handler () {
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {

        tv.setText(Arrays.toString(msg.getData().getByteArray("data")));
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    ar = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize); 

    shortbuffer = new short[bufferSize];
    bytebuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    ar.startRecording();

    tv.setText("Hello");

    int N = 0;

    // now you can start reading the bytes from the AudioRecord
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            while (true) {
                ar.read(bytebuffer, 0, bytebuffer.length);
                byte[] pkt = Arrays.copyOf(bytebuffer, bytebuffer.length);

                //tv.setText(Arrays.toString(pkt));

                b.putByteArray("data", pkt);
                msg.setData(b);
                uiCallback.sendMessage(msg);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    t.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    ar.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are sending the same Message multiple times in a loop, you have to obtain a new Message before sending it

Answer (score 0):

The weak reference is a tip for avoiding access to views that have been removed from their container (the activity for example).

A possible alternative solution is that you do something like this:

```
class YourSpecialAudioClass implements ISpecialAudioClass
{
/**this class can be used by the outside UI world, inside the implementation of the runnable in the CTOR*/
@override
public byte[] getData(){...}

public YourSpecialAudioClass(Runnable doSomethingWithDataRunnable)
  {
  this.doSomethingWithDataRunnable=doSomethingWithDataRunnable;
  this.handler=new Handler();
  }
...
  while(true)
    {
    ...
    this.handler.post(this.doSomethingWithDataRunnable);
    }
...
}
```

don't forget to handle stopping the thread from updating the UI when you don't need it, especially if the activity is being closed.